# Server Identification - SSL or "Manual"

Tags: ssl, encryption, cryptography

In my application, I want to check whether or not the server I am connecting to is trustable. Instead of using SSL, which would come with the cost of a certificate , I thought about creating my own identity check, where I would send a random string to the server at connection. The server would rsa encrypt the string with a hard-coded private key and send the result back. The client application would then decrypt the result with a hard coded public key (it has only the public key, not the private one). If the string it sent and the string it decrypted matched, the server's identity would be proven and the tcp communication would just be encrypted with AES (The AES key is transferred in rsa encrypted format after the server identity was proven).

Questions:

1. Is this approach viable and if yes, where are the weaknesses?
   (besides me having to keep the private key secret, obviously)
2. What advantages would I gain by using SSL with a bought certificate in this circumstance?
3. Would a self-signed SSL certificate also be enough in this circumstance? I plan to make the service publicly available.

Comment: The cost of a certificate is negligible or zero. The cost of rolling your own solution and getting it wrong could be enormous.

Comment: @EJP I get where you're coming from. So the best bet would be to have the client connect to a domain which redirects to my server and then from the server side, send a certificate for that domain, right? If yes, is it good to develop with a self-signed cert and when I go live, buy a cert from a trusted comany like Comodo or Thawte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check whether or not the server I am connecting to is trustable.

Both your approach and the approach with using SSL can not provide any information about how trustable the server is but offer only a way to identify the server, i.e. to make sure that your are talking with the expected server. The server can still be hacked and serve malware so you should not trust it just based on the identification.

> I thought about creating my own identity check, where I would send a random string to the server at connection ... rsa encrypt ... hard-coded private key ... hard coded public key ...

You are effectively trying to re-invent TLS with certificate pinning. It is not a requirement of TLS that certificates need be be bought from a public CA. You can simply create self-signed certs as long as the expected certificate or public key is known to the client in advance, i.e. before connecting. The main point of using certificates signed by a public CA instead of self-signed is, that it does not scale to have each certificate on the world installed into the clients browser/OS but it scales to have a few trust anchors (root CA) installed.

For more information on how to use TLS with certificate/public key pinning the this [page at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) which even includes code examples for various languages.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use TLS. Over time, mistakes in TLS have been found and fixed. To start with your own design and make the assumption that you could not make similar mistakes is a big risk.

You can create your own server certificate for free, especially if you are embedding the server public key in the client because then you are not dependent on a public CA to authenticate the server's identity.

You also introduce a weakness by using the private key to encrypt and the public key to decrypt, which is not what RSA was designed for (the *public* key is used to encrypt). To make the assumption that this is just fine, is another big risk.